# Facing trouble with python pip

Tags: python, pip

I need to install request using pip , but it showing me error *SyntaxError: invalid syntax*

```
>>> pip install requests
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Please let me know what is wrong with pip

Comment: `pip install requests` is supposed to be run on a terminal, and not on the Python interpreter :)

Comment: Yes I have try it on power shell and cmd, but no success

Comment: then try what i said you can do in IDLE

Answer (score 2):

you need to type it in cmd not in the IDLE. becuse IDLE is not an command prompt if you want to install something from IDLE type this

```
>>>from pip.__main__ import main
>>>main(#args splitted by space in list example:['install', 'requests'])
```

this is calling pip like `pip <commands>` in terminal. The commands will be seperated by spaces that you are doing there to.

Comment: then try what i said you can do in IDLE